# Convert linear polygons to lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, geometry-conversion

I have some long linear polygons that I'd rather store as lines but I'm not sure how best to do this. Ideally I'd have a line going through the centre of the polygon lengthways. I have two ideas of how to do this but I'm not sure how to implement them or to what extent they're possible. Perhaps there's already a tool out there that does this?

option one:
1. convert polygon to points at vertices
2. identify the two points furthest apart in each feature. I can do this in point distance but I'm not sure how to automate it
3. mask the area outside the polygon
4. run a cost path between the two points

option two:
1. convert polygon to points at vertices
2. Create theissen polygons around the points
3.(somehow) save the line along the middle between the theissen polygons?

Does anyone know how I can make either of these methods work or if there is an easier method. My Python is weak so I was going to try it in model builder but if I needs Python I can give it a go

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download the [ET Geowizards toolbox](http://www.ian-ko.com/) (Free) and use the [createCenterlines](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/createCenterlines.htm) tool. I think that should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: worked a treat!

Comment: Highly Recommend GeoWizards - has saved many, many hours in ArcGIS/Geoprocessing work.