# How to convert "linear" polygons to lines using NetTopologySuite?

Tags: nettopologysuite

If I have set of polygons representing country rivers, how to convert them to their linear representation using NetTopologySuite. I did some digging but i was unable to find exact function like [Create Centerlines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/79211/4977) in some other software (Free, but with usability limits).

[image]

I could just unpack polygons to linear geometry, but it would be better if it is cleaned up somehow. I am not sure how.